# iOS: instance method -setParameters not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlrequest

I'm updating old implementation. But I'm getting this error:

```
 instance method -setParameters not found
```

on this line:

```
[request setParameters:self.parameters];
```

But I found this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *parameters NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

This is how parameters is been set:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)aURL parameters:(NSArray *)theParameters files:(NSDictionary*)theFiles {
    return [self initWithURL:aURL
                      method:@"POST"
                  parameters:theParameters
                       files:theFiles];
}
```

or

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)aURL parameters:(NSArray *)theParameters {
    return [self initWithURL:aURL
                      method:nil
                  parameters:theParameters];
}
```

Basically is adding some parameters to NSURLRequest. My question to you guys there is way to replace setParameters to add the parameters to the NSURLRequest?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: @nspavlo, I'm updating this code to iOS 9.1 that is the reason I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Show the context of that declaration of the parameters property. Is that from the header of `NSURLRequest`? It doesn't look familiar.

Comment: @DuncanC, I have updated my original post

Comment: It would make no sense to have a property for URL parameters on an NSURLRequest. It would be like you feeding your dog by holding your dog and eating its food. The parameters belong to the URL not the request. The NSURLRequest has a URL, it is not a URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add URL parameters to an NSURLRequest. There is a property on NSURL for [parameterString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1412797-parameterstring?language=objc) but it is readonly, which is why you're only able to set it using the initializer. There's definitely no way to set URL parameters on an NSURLRequest. You can see them with `myReq.URL.parameterString` but definitely can't set them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify an `NSURLRequest` after init, you should use `NSMutableURLRequest` instead.